# Confuse in Binary Search when to use left < right ; left <= right ; and few more

Tags: binary-search

I've difficulty in understanding when to use:

```
while (left < right ) {
}
```

vs when to use:

```
while (left <= right ) {
}
```

Also while setting left and right boundaries sometimes we use:

```
left = mid
```

and sometime we use

```
left = mid + 1;
```

similarly

```
right = mid; vs
right = mid - 1;
```

Is there any fundamental I am missing in knowledge of Binary search ?

Comment: Hope this article help you - https://medium.com/swlh/binary-search-find-upper-and-lower-bound-3f07867d81fb

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The basic idea is to search and find the element:

```
public static int indexOf(int[] array, int target) {
   int lo = 0, hi = a.length - 1;
   while (lo <= hi) {
      // Key is in a[lo..hi] or may be it is not present.
      int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
      if      (target < a[mid]) hi = mid - 1;
      else if (target > a[mid]) lo = mid + 1;
      else return mid;
   }
   return -1;
}
```

We can also use `mid = (lo + hi) >>> 1` to compute the mid but using `(lo+hi)/2` may cause overflow. Now the confusion part:

> We use `while (lo <= hi)` if we are returning the match from inside
> the loop. We use `while (lo < hi)` when we want to exit the loop
> first and then use the result of `lo` or `hi` to return the match.

Good intro for binary search use cases: https://leetcode.com/discuss/general-discussion/786126/Python-Powerful-Ultimate-Binary-Search-Template.-Solved-many-problems

Comment: So do we know which one of the indexes (`lo` or `high`) to return or does that depend on the questions? If so, is it always simpler to just return within the loop?

Comment: @Liumx31 depends on the scenario of returning min or max value in a problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you divide an array you find the `mid` index. At this time you have two parts with a `mid` index. Since the array is sorted you compare the search element with `mid` index value.

If the search value is smaller than `mid` index value you know it is at left side otherwise it is at right side.

Now, you repeat the above step (divide into two parts, mid index etc.) for either left half (index 0 to mid - 1) or right half (index mid +1 to end). If the search value is same as `mid` index value then element is found and you stop processing.

This divide and compare process continues until you find the search element or left and right index (initially 0 and length-1) overlaps. Thats why the condition `left <= right`.

Comment: Yes I agree that part, but sometime left < right  works and sometime not. that is my confusion.

Comment: Yes left < right would work. You are checking my left index of the array part is not same as right index or exceeding the right index. If so no need to process further. So, I will process until `left < right`

Comment: For binary search visualisation check this: https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/Search.html. If you find this answer clarifies your doubts please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

use left <= right
when you are changing the mid index in the loop

```
 mid = right -1
 mid = left +1
```

use left < right
when you are assigning the left and right directly to mid

```
right = mid
left = mid+1
```